# What is this marker stone

Tags: hiking, germany

I walk a lot in Germany and I found many stones much like this on my route this weekend:

[image: Strange stone]

[image: Strange stone 2]

Along [this particular section of the walk](https://www.google.de/maps/dir/50.473537,7.5960769/50.4692985,7.6025537/@50.4714785,7.5983186,16.5z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e2?hl=en).

Most of the stones have two digit numbers. The one shown has 3. The top letters are "BP" and the bottom letters are "POST".

I thought that they might be mile/kilo-stones. However, they appeared regularly within 50 meters of each other with different numbers. The numbers written were also not consecutive. It can also not refer to altitude, because the numbers do not correlate. Perhaps it is a proprietary system?

Comment: The word looks like PQST to me, not POST?

Comment: That is just the quality of this particular stone. I am reasonably certain that the text says POST. However, now that I look at the picture again, I wouldn't put money on it. I am adding another reference picture.

Comment: Just a guess, but BP could refer to *Bundespost*?  That's the german post office, although theirs handles other communications means (or at least used to) also.  I don't know what the markers might have been for, but that may give you some ideas on how to search.

Comment: Maybe it's some kind of boundary marker.

Comment: @OlinLathrop It certainly could. My father suggested the same thing. The placement of these markers is extremely strange. The area where they are along the route of a brook in a valley. This area was extremely boggy when I walked there. I can't imagine someone would use this route for anything logistical.

Comment: Then maybe it's marking the spot where the previous 125 mail wagons sank into the muck.

Comment: *if* it is Bunderspost, then it could be the route of an old telephone cable

Comment: @Liam now that is an interesting proposition!

Comment: +1 Good question. I am from Germany and I've never seen this ;)

Comment: That's a lot of compression artifacts on those pictures. For *some reason*, they remind me of [these test images](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=JPEG&oldid=694102260#Effects_of_JPEG_compression).

Comment: They are frames from a video I made. I would have shared the video, but it has my children in them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are markers of the former "Deutsche Bundespost". They show where to find cable trays.

> Manchmal stehen sie unscheinbar am Wegesrand: Markierungssteine aus
>   Beton mit einem eingegossenen BP.
>
> Diese Markierungssteine markieren eine Kabeltrasse der Deutschen
>   Bundespost, der Vorgängerbehörde der heutigen AGs Deutsche Post,
>   Deutsche Telekom und Deutsche Postbank.

Freely interpreted:

Sometimes standing inconspicuous on the wayside: concreted marking stones with a moulded "BP" inside.

These stones mark cable trays of the "Deutschen Bundespost", the predecessor of todays "Deutsche Post AG", "Deutsche Telekom" and "Deutsche Postbank".

From "[Heimatarchiv](http://www.heimatarchiv-worringen.de/index.php/alle-artikel/denkmal-des-monats/56-2014-03-26)":

> Das BP steht für die Bundespost, genauer die Deutsche Bundespost. Der
>   Stein markiert den Verlauf der Telefonleitung von Köln nach Dormagen.
>   Diese wurde vor Jahren vom damaligen Fernmeldeamt der Deutschen
>   Bundespost verlegt und der Verlauf mit diesem Stein markiert.

Freely interpreted:

The "BP" stand for "Bundespost", the "Deutsche Bundespost" to be specific. The stone marks the way of the telephone cable from Cologne to "Dormagen". It was laid from the telecommunication center of the "Deutschen Bundespost" and its course marked with these stones.

[image: Marker stone]

Further reading:

- https://www.geschichtsspuren.de/forum/markierungen-steine-der-bundespost-t14523-10.html
- http://www.opencaching.de/viewcache.php?cacheid=176262

Comment: Amazing, thank you for the information! That must be it! Lots of information for me to digest there!